# add content to the page from tinymce

Tags: tinymce, contenteditable, redactor

Need to let admin user modify content on pages that are used by basic users without adding text to html, but from webpage.
I'd like to add the content that I modify in `textarea` of TinyMCE editor to the html page. What is the better way to realize that?
Something like - add text to the textarea, than press "save" button in textarea on monday_admin.html and this content from textarea will be saved to the monday.html (other page).

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you might want to look at inline editing. Tie the ability to use inline editing to an admin level account, and then they can edit the HTML page. THat way you can modify the content from the webpage. 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/inline/